# Different java version in .sh file and terminal MAC

Tags: macos, environment-variables, macos-mojave, java-home

I'm trying to set JAVA_HOME in macOS 10.14. Currently there are 2 jdk versions (`jdk-11.0.8.jdk`,   `jdk-14.0.2.jdk`) installed in `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines` and I've exported env variable in `.bash_profile`

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 11`
```

In terminal all is ok. `java -version` prints `11.0.8`, `echo $JAVA_HOME` shows 11's directory.
But in `~/test.sh` file `java -version` prints `14.0.2`, `$JAVA_HOME` is empty. I tried to set env var in `etc/profile` but no success. Does anyone know what could possibly cause this?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the wonderful world of POSIX semi-compatible shells :-)

From the bash man page:

> When  bash  is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a non-interactive shell
> with the --login option, it  first  reads  and  executes  commands  from  the  file
> /etc/profile,  if  that  file  exists.   After  reading  that  file,  it  looks for
> ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile, in that order, and reads  and  exe-
> cutes  commands  from  the  first one that exists and is readable.  The --noprofile
> option may be used when the shell is started to inhibit this behavior.

Note that simply running a script does not execute the *~/.bash_profile* script as the script is neither interactive nor a "login" shell. One solution is to set the `BASH_ENV` var to an appropriate initialization script.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you know where to set `BASH_ENV` ?